# How to load random line from text file in android?

Tags: android

I have this piece of code;

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.game));

try {
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {

        System.out.println(s.nextLine());

    }
} finally {
    s.close();
}
```

How can I make to load a random line from this piece of code?

Thanks.

Comment: If the file is small, reading to a string array is the way to go.  If it's big, you'll need a different approach.  How big is the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the lines into another data structure such as an `ArrayList` and then use `Random` to generate a random index number.

Here's some code to put it into an ArrayList:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.game));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(s.nextLine());      
    }
} finally {
    s.close();
}
```

This code will return a random line:

```
public static String randomLine(ArrayList list) {
    return list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First load all of them from file into a `String` array then randomly pick one of them from that `String` array.

Answer (score 1):

lets supose that you did the collecting to the String array `lines`:

```
int randomLine = (int)(Math.random()*lines.length);
```

there you got your random line.

Edit: oh well, you could use just `String[]`